# How to build android and ios application using existing ASP.net console application

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net, angularjs

I want to build android and iOS application using existing ASP.net console application. Below are my folder structure. My project is build with ASP.net and Angular 4. In my project app.ColorSelector is a startup project it contains the angular code.

[image]

Inside color selector folder.

[image]

is there any way to build the android and iOS.

Comment: see https://www.tutorialspoint.com/xamarin that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at PhoneGap: https://phonegap.com/
That's one of the technologies that lets you build a cross platform app that hosts a "web view", which is essentially a webpage within a native app-shell. That way you can leverage existing code. Of course, you may need to make few adjustments, but it should theoretically work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We have tried using phonegap but it need index file for the start up but in our case asp.net having startup.cs file.

Comment: You might need to port that asp.net code to a static-html website, where you handle dynamic page-content changes via javascript. I'm not sure a native app can act as a web-server of any kind, and if even so, asp.net would probably not be the first one supported. If that site is large, and you want to keep it, another approach would be to keep hosting it at some public domain, optimize its rendering for small screens, and just use mobile browser (or, perhaps, create a phonegap app that proxies all http calls, which should be possible, but all you're saving is the browser's address bar space).